# Topology not executing in Apache Storm Giving error in owner summary

Tags: apache-storm, topology

[storm.yaml file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ySmW.png)When I submit topology in my cluster setup then topology divide the task but not execute, in the process of debugging I click on owner summary and got this screen.

Could someone please let us know why this happens and a way to resolve it?

Is this is the reason why topology is not executing.[error screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/megKp.png)

Comment: Can you also show your storm.yaml file?

Comment: I added it above

Answer (score 0):

I answered similarly in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036336/topology-does-not-execute-on-local-cluster) how to remove this red notice.
You get a red notice in case of using a default scheduler.
To remove this notice, just for peace of mind, you have to use RAS - resource aware scheduler - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036336/topology-does-not-execute-on-local-cluster) out.

In my humble opinion, the red notice in the owner screen doesn't affect your topology. Show your topology code.